# suction-cup lamps for video lighting

Tags: lighting

Here's an idea that I wonder if anybody has tried...

In order to get better lighting for indoor video camera work, get a few small pendant lamps, each with a suction-cup.  Just stick them onto a nearby wall, plug in to an outlet, and shoot.

Question: where can I find some suction cups with which to do this?

Answer (score 1):

While I have not tried this.  I imagine the problem would be getting a good enough seal to hold the weight of the light and cable.  Having your (generally pricy) light with a hot, sensitive bulb in it go smashing to the floor because the suction didn't quite hold is generally a risk most people wouldn't want to take.  Simple tripods are easier to setup and are easier to adjust the positioning (you aren't confined to positioning it on a wall for example).